# How do you access the files in a mounted folder in Ubuntu using C#?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, mounted-volumes

Running Ubuntu 20.04, I have a mounted folder that `gio mount` lists in the format of

afp://myusername@ServerName.local/sharedDirectory/

I would like to access the files in sharedDirectory from a C# program, however the file utilities (like `Path.GetFullPath()` or `Directory.EnumerateFiles()`) treat the "afp://...sharedDirectory" as a partial path and prepend the current directory, so when I try to enumerate files I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

Should I be using a different string for the path?

Comment: If the volume is mounted, shouldn't it have a path on the file system rather than a URI? I would think the URI is what you use to mount the volume, but then you have an actual mount point that starts like `/mnt/blahblah` or something.

Comment: The only reference I can find to the shared folder is in ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata, but it does not provide a path.